# Asp.Net Menu comes from Sql Server "MenuItemClick" Event not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic

I am using `asp:menu` control and getting the data to bind the menu is from `Sql Server` *Database*.

If I select a sub item from menu then parent item must be showed as selected. 
To do this functionality i tried to write code in "MenuItemClick" Event. But its not firing.
Here is a my menu:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false"
    Orientation="Horizontal" BackColor="#B39DDB" > 
    <StaticSelectedStyle />
    <StaticMenuItemStyle BackColor="#B39DDB" />
    <LevelMenuItemStyles>
        <asp:MenuItemStyle />
    </LevelMenuItemStyles>
</asp:Menu>
```

Binding it here:

```
Private Sub PopulateMenu(dt As DataTable, parentMenuId As Integer, parentMenuItem As MenuItem)
    Dim currentPage As String = Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim menuItem As New MenuItem() With { _
         .Value = row("menu_id").ToString(), _
         .Text = row("name").ToString(), _
          .NavigateUrl = row("location").ToString(), _
        .Selected = row("location").ToString().EndsWith(currentPage, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) _
        }
        If parentMenuId = 0 Then
            Menu1.Items.Add(menuItem)
            Dim dtChild As DataTable = Me.GetData(Integer.Parse(menuItem.Value))
            PopulateMenu(dtChild, Integer.Parse(menuItem.Value), menuItem)
        Else
            parentMenuItem.ChildItems.Add(menuItem)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Here is i am adding a handler:

```
Protected Sub Menu1_MenuItemClick(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuEventArgs) Handles Menu1.MenuItemClick
        Try
            Session("menu_id") = Menu1.SelectedValue.ToString
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Appreciate your support.

Comment: You say the Event is not firing, but I don't see you adding a handler to the Event in the code you have shown

Comment: Yes, now i added a handler

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN: [MenuItem.NavigateUrl Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitem.navigateurl(v=vs.110).aspx)

> A menu item can be in one of two modes: selection mode or navigation mode. By default, a menu item is in selection mode. To put a menu item into navigation mode, set the menu item's NavigateUrl property to a value other than an empty string ("").
>
> When a menu item is in navigation mode, all selection events are disabled for that menu item. Clicking the menu item in navigation mode takes the user to the specified URL. You can optionally set the Target property to specify the window or frame in which to display the linked content.

If you want your Menu to respond to a Click event that is handled in your Code-Behind, you will need to bind the Menus `OnMenuItemClick` event to your function by adding this section to the `asp:Menu` declaration

```
OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick"
```

And, also do not set the property `.NavigateUrl`

If you want to also direct the user to another page, then you will have to issue a Response.Redirect inside your `Menu1_MenuItemClick` event handler, something like:

```
Response.Redirect("About.aspx")
```

Comment: I need an `ID` of the `menuitem` and store in a `session`. So how can i get it without `menuitemclick`,when menu comes from `database`.

Comment: You can do all that, just use a Reponse.Redirect after `Session("menu_id")`,  and don't put the Url in the .NavigateUrl property

Comment: `Menu1_MenuItemClick` is not working. How do i use that code.

Comment: `OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick"` is not firing. Inside its block ,nothing is working.

Comment: Did you clear the value on the `.NavigateUrl` property or is it still set?

Comment: Here's my menu: `<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false"
                       Orientation="Horizontal" BackColor="#B39DDB" OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick"> 
                   
                        <StaticSelectedStyle />
                        <StaticMenuItemStyle BackColor="#B39DDB" />
                        <LevelMenuItemStyles>
                            <asp:MenuItemStyle />
                        </LevelMenuItemStyles>
                        
                    </asp:Menu>`

Comment: And what about the `.NavigateUrl` property in your code-behind, is that being set or not? You should not be setting a value on it for the MenuItemClick event to fire

Comment: Where should i set `.NavigateUrl` property In a code behind and how can i assign selected value in a session?

Comment: In your `PopulateMenu` remove the line for `.NavigateUrl`.
In your `Menu1_MenuItemClick` load from your database the menu option `Menu1.SelectedValue` (menu_id = Menu1.SelectedValue).
Use the value in `location` in the Response.Redirect

Comment: I can do this if i have the `menu` in a next page, in my condition only this page contains the menu and the next page is without that menu.

Comment: I don't think I can help you anymore on this problem. It is moving in to specific Debug issues which are out of scope for StackOverflow and near impossible to do remotely. Your original question on how to get the MenuItemClick event handler to work should be resolved by this answer, any further specific problems you are having should be asked under a new question with the usual guidelines.